# Cases titled/styled US v. some property (seizure)

Tags: united-states, title

In these made-up property seizure cases patterned after real ones, what is the role of the item in the defendant position? Is such property somehow a legal person or some kind of legal fiction?

*United States v. $3,120,768*

*United States v. 1967 Buick Skylark*

Comment: @Trish: Yes, thank you. My searches didn't locate that.

Comment: That's because I asked the exact inverse there, which happens when the case gets into the next instance. However, that's no problem - it's good to have duplicates.

Comment: @Trish: The answer by user6726 is helpful but not entirely satisfying. Questions such as who represents the property, who pays for that representation, does the Buick ever win, what classification terms are used to refer to this type of case, etc., remain unanswered. I didn't ask those in the question I posted but my use of "role" might have led to an answer that included some of that information.